# Reset a size class (i.e. Compact W/Compact H) to Any W/Any W on XCode 6

Tags: xcode, ios8, size-classes, xcode6-beta7

Loving XCode 6/iOS8's new way (using size classes) of doing Autolayouting (despite it being a pretty hard puzzle to solve at times).

But how does one reset one of the size classes back to Any/Any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set you size class to `wAny hAny` 
Now you should see constraints installed outside this size class as greyed out in the pane on the left:
[image: left pane]

Select this constraint in the list and in the detail inspector pane on the right you should see this:

[image: detail pane]

Here you see I installed a `wRegular hAny` constraint.
Hit the little x to delete this constraint in this size class.
Repeat for any other constraints you have.

Once these constraints are no longer installed in any size classes you can select and delete them in the left pane.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the Width/Height, take your cursor to the middle square and select it.  That will set it at Any/Any.

Edit:  I think I may have misunderstood.  If, for example, you are working in wCompact hRegular, and you don't want those changes anymore and you want it to "inherit" from Any/Any, then you'll have to go about either uninstalling or deleting the constraints you created specifically for that size class.  When you have your view controller outline showing, and the constraints appearing, the ones not grayed out are active for that size class.  Check each one to see if any are specific to the size class you're working in (such as wCompact hRegular).

You can also uninstall or delete any additional UI objects you added to that size class specifically.

Hope that helps.